# MAMP PRO - Memory / WordPress Issue

Tags: php, wordpress, mamp

I'm running a local install of WordPress and using the newest version of Mamp Pro. When I go to save a custom menu, or generate a form (using gravity forms) the POST times out.

I have increased the memory in the php.ini file to 256M as well as inside of the WP_CONFIG file. I've also increased the time limit from 30 seconds to 60.

I know for a fact it's not a plugin or theme issue, and I've reinstalled both MAMP, WordPress etc many times.

I've seen other posts and it seemed to just be a memory issue, but that has not fixed my problem at all.

This is NOT a problem on my other computer, but just on my MB Pro. I'm not sure if there is some other PHP setting or some other MAMP setting I could try to configure in order to allow it to work.

Also, just for the record, if I push everything to my live server (Media Temple) there are no issues, so I know it's my local machine.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In php.ini, try [turning `display_errors` to on](http://www.jhuskisson.com/code-tidbits/re-enabling-error-reporting-in-mamp) and see if anything turns up.
 The only other thing I could imagine is that your install is having trouble writing to MAMP's MySQL database.

Comment: display_errors are on and not seeing anything. I temporarily remedied it by setting MAMP PRO to use the MAMP ports instead of the default ports, but now I have to use :8888 in the URL's. It's not the end of the world, just annoying as to why that would cause the issue.